# Добавлять имена по нажатию в favorites

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Есть список recyclerView, в котором инициализирую имена:

```
 private void initName() {
    categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(new Category(getString(R.string.one)));
    categories.add(new Category(getString(R.string.two)));
    categories.add(new Category(getString(R.string.three)));
    categories.add(new Category(getString(R.string.four)));
    categories.add(new Category(getString(R.string.five)));
    categories.add(new Category(getString(R.string.six)));
}
```

Где дальше для каждого имени проделываю переход, примерно следующим образом:

```
 private void initializeAdapter() {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(categories, position -> {
        Intent intent;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), One.class);
                break;
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при переходе/нажатию на имена они с добавлялись с помощью SharedPreference в какую то активность(что то типо favorites).

Comment: Непонятно, в чем именно проблема? Как определить, какой элемент кликнули? Как записать в SharedPrefreences? Как передать в запускаемую Activity параметр? Как его там извлечь из интента? Как хранить в SharedPreferences списк? :)

Comment: Ну получается что да
нажатие происходит, на какой элемент тоже понятно, ну по крайней мере мне, так как переходит в другую активность с его именем. Но как определить это нажатие в sharedPreference? После инициализации так понимаю нужно написать что то подобное 'Editor e = sp.edit();
 e.putStringSet("strSetKey", categories);
 e.apply();
    '
   И после этого как то считывать инфу что кликнули по нему.